# Purpose of the Tomcat conf folder

Tags: tomcat, configuration-files

This is just for my own confirmation really.

Is the `<CATALINA_HOME>/conf` folder in Tomcat for configuring Tomcat itself, rather than configuring application-specific settings?

I assume application-specific config files could be put into this folder if I wanted but it's not a good idea partly because it's the wrong place and they wouldn't appear on the classpath, thus meaning that the files wouldn't be accessible using `getResourceAsStream()`.

Is that a good summary of what the folder is and isn't for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm pretty sure [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/introduction.html#Directories_and_Files) is correct:

> Configuration files and related DTDs. The most important file in here is server.xml. It is the main configuration file for the container.

Answer (score 1):

The `conf` folder contains all the configurations related to tomcat in the form of xml. We can change the port number of our server inside the `server.xml` file, which is present in the `conf` folder by using `<connector port="8080">`.